# zend framework : "A project profile was not found"  zf version 1.11.7

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to develop a project in zend framework. I have created a project **gil** using command line as follows then I entered to the project directory in command line and tried to create an action but I got an error as follows. I am using Windows XP and XAMPP and my Zend frameworks version is 1.11.7.

```
   C:\xampp\htdocs\zframework12>zf create project gil
    Creating project at C:/xampp/htdocs/zframework12/gil

    C:\xampp\htdocs\zframework12>cd gil

    C:\xampp\htdocs\zframework12\gil>zf create action add index
                           An Error Has Occurred
     A project profile was not found.

    Zend Framework Command Line Console Tool v1.9.0
    Details for action "Create" and provider "Action"
      Action
        zf create action name controller-name[=index] view-included[=1] module


C:\xampp\htdocs\zframework12\gil>
```

Please help to sort out this issue

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

In the second prompt, you type: cd gil . So, you'll move in the gil directory. This directory doesn't contain the zf xml file called **.zfproject.xml** (hidden). You should type:

```
zf create action add index
```

In the root directory: *C:\xampp\htdocs\zframework12*

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
When I created the project using zf create project gil, I got a new directory gil on the main folder zframework12, and the .zfproject.xml file in in the new directory gil so I entered to the the directory gil then tried to create the action, then I got the error

Comment: Ok. Did you check the permissions on the .zfproject.xml file?

Comment: thanks bitfox, I am using windows XP in my local machine,so I think I dont need to worry about permissions, right ?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, if you have xp, that's right. I found an interesting link: http://www.leoganda.net/solving-zend-framework-error-an-error-has-occurred-a-project-profile-was-not-found/ . Does it resolve your problem?

Comment: but now I am getting another error, Provider action is not a valid provider, I cant even create a project now using command line

Comment: What does the include_path contain?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, which caused by moving from one folders into another that lead to missing deleting hiden file **.zfproject.xml**.  The solution is creating a new project "create project newname" and move all former files into this one.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with zf 1.12.9.

In my case, i was trying to execute command 
`zf1 enable layout` from the parent dir to the project.

The solution was to go to the correct directory and then execute command.

This link helped me with my problem

[original solution source](http://puspabangun.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/solving-zend-framework-error-%E2%80%9Can-error-has-occurred-a-project-profile-was-not-found%E2%80%9D/)

Answer (score -2):

copy your `zf.bat` file to your new project 'gil' directory